# How to run a java program including a .jar file

Tags: java, linux, jakarta-ee, ubuntu, javac

I have 2 classes

```
CLASS1 (the main class)
    - calls threading glass


CLASS2 (the threading class)
    - calls function
    - calls json.simple.jar functons
```

and a .JAR (https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)

```
jar/json.simple.jar
```

Now the main problem is that i actualy managed to make both classes to compile with those commands

```
javac -d . -cp '.:jar/json.simple.jar' *.java;
```

this will create a folder named package1 and then when i try to run it it gives me the error

```
java javanolo.CLASS1 -jar 'jar/json.simple.jar';


Selected (9) IPS ... <-- this is the first **println**
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/parser/ParseException
        at javanolo.CLASS1.main(CLASS1.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.parser.ParseException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 1 more
```

and i assume this is because it is not finding some of the json simple functions. Why that? I've imported them

```
// json encode/decode
import org.json.simple.JSONValue;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
```

and i am sure that i have imported the .jar, because if i run

```
javac -d . *.java;


error :

import org.json.simple.JSONValue;
^
CLASS1.java:14: error: package org.json.simple does not exist
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
^
CLASS1.java:15: error: package org.json.simple.parser does not exist
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
^
CLASS2.java:16: error: package org.json.simple does not exist
import org.json.simple.JSONValue;
^
CLASS2.java:17: error: package org.json.simple does not exist
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
^
CLASS2.java:18: error: package org.json.simple.parser does not exist
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
^
CLASS2.java:148: error: cannot find symbol
public Map<String,String> openAndGetGeoDataByProxy(String ip,String port,int timeout) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ParseException
                                                                    ^
symbol:   class ParseException
location: class CLASS2
CLASS2.java:99: error: cannot find symbol
} catch (ParseException ex) {
^
symbol:   class ParseException
location: class CLASS2
CLASS2.java:188: error: cannot find symbol
Object jsonObject = JSONValue.parse(line);
^
symbol:   variable JSONValue
location: class CLASS2
CLASS2.java:191: error: cannot find symbol
JSONObject jsonArray = (JSONObject)jsonObject;
^
symbol:   class JSONObject
location: class CLASS2
CLASS2.java:191: error: cannot find symbol
JSONObject jsonArray = (JSONObject)jsonObject;
^
symbol:   class JSONObject
location: class CLASS2
CLASS2.java:194: error: cannot find symbol
JSONObject jsonArray2 = (JSONObject)jsonArray.get("array_result");
^
symbol:   class JSONObject
location: class CLASS2
CLASS2.java:194: error: cannot find symbol
JSONObject jsonArray2 = (JSONObject)jsonArray.get("array_result");
^
symbol:   class JSONObject
location: class CLASS2
```

so i know for sure that json-simple.jar is being used when compilation.

1. The main question is, how can i run CLASS1 and CLASS2 with that .jar file?
2. Why LINUX based system is so different then the WINDOWS NETBEANS? I mean java is platform independent ...
3. Ho can i connect NETBEANS to my server trough SFTP so i can code there directly.

Thanks.

**EDIT TRIES**

i have tried the following commands, none of them works, it gives me the message like i was running the `java -help` command

try1
`java -cp .;jar/json.simple.jar javanolo.CLASS1`

try2
`java -cp .;'/root/folder/folder/jar/json.simple.jar' javanolo.CLASS1`

try3
`java -cp .;/root/folder/folder/jar/json.simple.jar javanolo.CLASS1`

can anyone help me please (would be better on chat)? i really need this

Comment: The problem might be with the relative path. Try to replace json.simple.jar with the full absolute path for that jar

Comment: Because the json .jar isn't in your classpath. http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-compile-and-launch-java-code-from-command-line/

Comment: Ingo gave the right answer, so you will be fine for now. But may I suggest to read about naming and coding conventions in Java, otherwise your questions and code examples look odd to everyone else.

Comment: i tried something but didn''t work, see **EDIT TRIES** at the main post please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this:

```
java javanolo.CLASS1 -jar 'jar/json.simple.jar'
```

you run your class and give the rest of the command line, i.e. `-jar jar/json.simple.jar` as arguments.

What you want is:

```
java -cp .;jar/json.simple.jar javanolo.CLASS1
```

or, in a UNIX shell:

```
java -cp .:jar/json.simple.jar javanolo.CLASS1
```

Note that your class path is the same in compilation and execution.

Comment: hi there. i tried something but didn''t work, see **EDIT TRIES** at the main post please. i don't know what to do next, can you please help me? i really need this

Comment: @Damian On UNIX, replace the `;` with `:`

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, i figured out myself, and i forgot to set the accepted answer. Thank you very much, now i understand how it works ... but i don't understand why JAVA is so complicated, i mean C# is way better ... and i tought "platform independent" is an advantage

Comment: @Damian Well, the PATH syntax predates Java, and Java Command Line Tools like javac, java etc. have adapted to it - which is arguably a good thing for developers familiar with the command line of their platform. For novices, it is more difficult. Hence, it is not so much Java as pre-existing conventions that makes things hard.

Comment: Yes, i agree with you, but from my point of view, JAVA seems to be more difficult then other languages, and you have to write twice the code, witch is not time efficient. Thank you again. Also i have another question about running exec command in background. Look at my account if you have some time.